# httpd memory could not be written on winxp

Tags: windows-xp, httpd

I have a apache server on a winxp box, ocassionaly I got a

`"httpd error, memory could not be written"` error, here is what I found in the apache error-log

`[Sat Sep 12 10:58:34 2009] [error] [client 113.68.84.79] Invalid URI in request ;\xece\r\xd5m\xed{\xbcf\xbf\xffq\bZNB\xf0a\xf9\x13\xf3[\x06Y\x02G\xca\xc5\xf3\x9ft\x89b\xed\xb5m\x9f\x1c\xa6\x03\x10\xee\xe9G\xb5\xe0glLf\xd4eFT\x8f.{Ysl\x89\x05\x18\x0f\x0fp\xdd\xaf\x11G\xbe\xbf\x96/Pr\x9e\xf4\x89\xf2\xd4^mA\x13y2\xe3\x95\xaeD\x02\xa7*G\xe4\x1d\x07r^\xaf_J\xf7\xbc\x90\x17\xda\x90\x17\xec\xd4>\xe8\xe4\xfcU\x04\xbc2V\xe1\x170\xeb

Error in my_thread_global_end(): 66 threads didn't exit

[Sat Sep 12 11:08:43 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.

[Sat Sep 12 11:08:51 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.2.3 configured -- resuming normal operations`

Anybody can tell what this means and where the problem is ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone is trying to bring your server down.  I would block that IP 113.68.84.79, in fact unless you are servicing clients to this netblock in china, block the whole thing on your firewall:

```
inetnum:      113.64.0.0 - 113.95.255.255
netname:      CHINANET-GD
descr:        CHINANET Guangdong province network
descr:        Data Communication Division
descr:        China Telecom
```

Then, make sure you update your PHP to the latest version...(5.2.10)... at the time of writing this...

Comment: I had port forwarding on my router which directs http(80) packets to the server box ( 192.168.1.1 ), I do need to server for that ip block, any handy way to work around? Thanks in advance.

Comment: correction: server box( 192.168.1.100 )

Comment: Hmm, are you using MySQL?  If so what version? This could also be related to a MYSQL bug...

Comment: Block it in your router - but note - this isn't a fix for whatever the problem is, its a temporarily work around.